# Can I iterate through an array during a comparison?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
s = Array.new 

s << 19 
while (s.last + 19) < 100000 do
  s << s.last + 19 
end
```

This^ works. s is an array of all factors of 19 below 100,000. 
I'm trying to, in a succinct statement, find all numbers in s where the reverse of that number is also in the array. Ex: 176 and 671.

```
reflections= s.select { |num| num.to_s.reverse == s.each.to_s }
```

I know this is wrong, but how can I check each reversed item against the entire array?

Comment: Sounds like an O(N^2) operation to me. Or O(N) if you build an intermediate structure for searching.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to edit your question & title to focus more on what your question is (the second half) - the title and first half seem unrelated to your question...

Comment: All factors or all multiples?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
reflections = s.select { |num| s.include?(num.to_s.reverse.to_i) }
```

Although it produces results that you probably didn't anticipate

```
s = [176, 234, 671, 111]

reflections = s.select { |num| s.include?(num.to_s.reverse.to_i) }

reflections # => [176, 671, 111]
```

These are all valid results according to your logic.

Excluding self-match is pretty straighforward:

```
s = [176, 234, 671, 111]

reflections = s.select do |x|
  x = x.to_s
  r = x.reverse
  (x != r) && s.include?(r.to_i)
end

reflections # => [176, 671]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
reflections = s & s.map{|num| num.to_s.reverse.to_i}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
reverse_array = s.select {|num| num.to_s == num.to_s.reverse }
```

UPDATE:

After checking I found this will work:

```
myarr = ""
s = (1..1000)    
s.select{ |num| 

unless s.include?(num.to_s.reverse.to_i)   
   myarr << num.to_s
end

}
```

Finally, the `myarr` will contain all the numbers whose reverse is present in array `s`.

Comment: No, that only gives palindromes. 176 and 671 would not be counted.